# Application-defined or object-defined error or color-filling

Tags: vba, excel, colors

I am trying to add a color-filling code into a worksheet_change private sub to highlight the cell where date value has been changed. This macro also updated the referenced database after any change has been made in date column (Column 1 or A). Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If strChk = "Don't Change Yet" Then Exit Sub
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
    r = Target.Row
    c = Target.Column
    If openMode = True Then Exit Sub
    If Trim(Cells(Target.Row, 1)) = "" Then Exit Sub
    If r = 2 Then Exit Sub
    If r = 3 Then Exit Sub
    If Not c = 1 Then Exit Su
    If Not IsNumeric(Cells(Target.Row, 2)) Then
        MsgBox "no orca number"
        Exit Sub
        End If

    If Not IsDate(Cells(Target.Row, 1)) Then
        MsgBox "Target date is invalid! Weird, right?"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim strsqla As String
        strsqla = "select target_date, orca, cow from orca " & _
        "where orca_id = " & Cells(Target.Row, 2)


    Dim adoSQLcon As ADODB.Connection

    Set adoSQLcon = New ADODB.Connection
    adoSQLcon.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=ENV_AC_Nording_dw_DEV;Data Source=S0662K806"

    Dim adoSQLRst As ADODB.Recordset

    Set adoSQLRst = New ADODB.Recordset
    adoSQLRst.Open strsqla, adoSQLcon, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

    If adoSQLRst.RecordCount > 0 Then
        If IsDate(Target.Value) Then
            adoSQLRst!target_date = Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value
            MsgBox "Date Updated"
        End If
        If Not Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value = "" Then
            adoSQLRst!ORCA = Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value
            MsgBox "ORCA Description Updated"
        End If
        If Not Cells(Target.Row, 8).Value = "" Then
            adoSQLRst!COW = Cells(Target.Row, 8).Value
            MsgBox "CoW Devices Updated"
        End If
        adoSQLRst.Update
    End If


    adoSQLRst.Close
    Set adoSQLRst = Nothing

    adoSQLcon.Close
    Set adoSQLcon = Nothing


    Cells(Target.Row, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

End Sub
```

So the code I added is "Cells(Target.Row, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)". So I want to highlight the cell after changed. But it ended up with this Run-time error '1004':Application-defined or object-defined error. So I was wondering if anyone could help me with this. Cuz I have tried all different types of color-filling codes I can find from website but all of them generated this error. 
Thank you very much for any help could provide.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the context ? (tag the question please)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So I have a table which the first column is the date for different tasks. Now I want to manually revise the date cell and want to highlight  the changed cell color with yellow (RGB (255,255,0)). Also, the changed date will be updated back to referenced database. But the code I added doesn't work and it generated the application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: By context, I believe @Blusky meant, is this a VBA macro in Excel?  Including those tags helps get the right people looking at your question.

Comment: Oh Sorry guys. Yes, it's Excel VBA.

Comment: It's worth noting (but may not be the basis of your current problem) that there's no constraint on the size of the input parameter Target, so you should always allow for that range being more than a single cell when looking at its properties (like Row or Column) and processing the range based on those properties.

Answer (score 0):

First replace:

```
If Not c = 1 Then Exit Su
```

with

```
If Not c = 1 Then Exit Sub
```

*There may be other problems.*

Comment: Gary's Student, thank you for your reply. Sorry I missed "b" when I pasted the code here.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `Cells(Target.Range.Row, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)`

I am not sure it will work but this is how I used it in my own script.

Comment: Hi Divin3, thank you for your reply. But seems it leads another error: Compile error: Argument not optional.